# What system is well-suited for a role-playing game based on Tokyo Ghoul?

Tags: system-for-setting

I really love the world of the manga [*Tokyo Ghoul*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Ghoul), and I would like create a role-playing game using the setting. However, I'm new to role-playing games so I don't know many systems. Which role-playing game system would be good for this setting?

Comment: I do not think we can really answer this. It seems to be a recommendation question, which we don't do here. It's also unclear if you want to _play_ in this world using an existing game, or want to _build_ a game using an existing system for inspiration (although probably both questions are out of scope here)

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a traditional discussion forum, and we've [had to admit that requests for system or setting recommendations don't work well in our format](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5747/4398). However, we've got [a list of other places that might be able to help](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/43980). I hope it's useful, and please remember us when you have questions about whatever system you decide to use!